# Continuous Delivery tool for Cloud Foundry

Tags: jenkins, deployment, cloud-foundry

I'm using Jenkins for Continuous Integration tool with DevOps tools like JIRA, Confluence, Crowd, SonarQube, Hygieia, etc.
But the environments are changed to deploy microservices to PaaS.
So I got the issues to resolve below.

1. Deployment Monitoring

   - to view which application is deployed to what instance with which version.
2. Canary Deployment

   - deploy to 1 instance and then deploy to all instances(after manual approval or auto).
3. Deploy to Cloud Foundry

   - more specifically IBM Bluemix

So I examined Spinnaker but I found that the cloud driver for CF is no longer maintained.
https://github.com/spinnaker/clouddriver/pull/1749

Do you know another open-sourced CD tool?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at concourse : https://concourse-ci.org/

Its open source, you can us it to deploy either application or cloud foundry. It's a central tool for DevOps. Basically you have pipelines that can trigger tasks (manually or automatically). You have some already created ressources (github connector, etc ...) but you can also create your own tasks. Its running docker containers as workers to execute tasks/jobs.

Best,

Comment: Thanks. I took a look into concourse. But it has no plug-ins. I need to connect with another DevOps tools like JIRA, etc. Maybe I have to develop jenkins plugin to use it as CD tool.

Answer (score 0):

I find it relatively easy to integrate a CD server to any PaaS provider.  You will have to either use a plugin or create your own integration.

My top two recommendations would be [gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com) or [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) in that order.

Given your preference for Jira, you might prefer Bamboo as it has very good integration with the rest of that Atlassian tools but it is not open source.